# Simplificar Função de probabilidades com prioridade

Tags: php, array, random

Tenho esta função que funciona como eu quero.
Ela recebe um valor entre -2 a 2 para definir a prioridade para escolher entre duas strings.

A minha questão é: **Como posso simplificar a função?**

```
function random_str($val){
   if($var == '-2') { $out = array('str1','str2','str2','str2'); }else
   if($var == '-1') { $out = array('str1','str2','str2'); }else
   if($var ==  '0') { $out = array('str1','str2',); }else
   if($var ==  '1') { $out = array('str1','str1','str2'); }else
   if($var ==  '2') { $out = array('str1','str1','str1','str2'); }
   return $out[array_rand($out)];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analisando seus `if` independente do valor ele sempre vai ter 2 elementos que são o `str1` e `str2`, depois vendo a diferença dos outros significa que quando for menor que `0` então precisa ter `str2` e quando for mair que `0` precisa ter `str1`.

```
function random_str($val){
    // padrão
    $out = array('str1', 'str2');

    while ($var != 0) {

        // menor que zero
        if ($var < 0) {
            array_push($out, 'str2');
            $var++;
        } else { // maior que zero
            array_push($out, 'str1');
            $var--;
        }
    }
    return $out[array_rand($out)];
}
```

Dessa forma funciona até se informar valores menor que `-2` e maior que `2` seguindo a mesma lógica, caso não queira adicione um `if/return`.

Comment: Boa, gostei desta solução! ;)